# Is there a clean way of defining a Java interface method that has different parameters for each implementation class?

Tags: java, interface

For example, say I have an interface that defines the method `action(...)` and I have three (in reality way more) classes that implement `action` with different parameters like so:

```
public class Class1 implements SomeInterface {
    public int action(int num) { ... }
}

public class Class2 implements SomeInterface {
    public String action(String string) { ... }
}

public class Class3 implements SomeInterface {
    public double action(double dub) { ... }
}
```

I feel like this isn't possible, but there's got to be some way to tell the user that each of these classes have an `action` method; maybe there's a way for it to dynamically accept arguments?

**EDIT:** What if we don't know that there is exactly one parameter? For example, is something like this possible?

```java
interface SomeInterface<T, T, ..., T> {
    T action(T t1, S s, ..., U u);
}
```

I feel like this is a really strange question, so I'll try to provide some more context. I'm working on a card game where there are different Action Cards that do different things, and require different information. I thought an Action Card interface was in order here, but then I ran into the issue of how to specify `action` when each implementation class needs totally different parameters and a different *number* of parameters as opposed to them implementing the exact same method differently or them each requiring the same number of parameters. For this reason, it is my understanding that generics won't work here but maybe I'm wrong or there's a better way of doing this altogether; perhaps the interface was the wrong way to do it from the start?

Comment: Let's say you have a variable `x` declared like `SomeInterface x = ...;`. And you want to call `x.action`. How do you, or the compiler, type-check the call? Should `x.action("hello")` compile?

Comment: As far as your edit goes: you can have multiple generic type parameters: seeing things like `SomeInterface<T, U, V>` is not uncommon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html):

```
interface SomeInterface<T> {
    T action(T t);
}

class Class1 implements SomeInterface<Integer> {
    public Integer action(Integer i) { return null; }
}

class Class2 implements SomeInterface<String> {
    public String action(String s){ return null; }
}

class Class3 implements SomeInterface<Double> {
    public Double action(Double d) { return null; }
}
```

Generics can only be used for object types, so you have to use primitive wrappers instead of primitives.